# MongoDB: strategies for resolving a race condition

Tags: php, mongodb

We have a scenario where we need to store multiple feeds under a site model as following:

```
{
  id: site_id
  name: site_name
  feeds: [
    {
      url: feed_url_1
      date: feed_update_date_1
    },
    {
      url: feed_url_2
      date: feed_update_date_2
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Since `feeds` is an array, we can update it with `$set`, `$push` or `$addToSet`.

2 different race condition (write skew) may occur when our concurrent application (queue) try to update the same site model.

If we pick `$set`, and guard duplicate on client side, then if 2 queues are writing to the same site, one feed maybe lost with following sequence.

```
Given a wordpress site, extract 2 feeds (RSS and ATOM), dispatch to Q1 and Q2.
Q1: load existing feed, check RSS feed is new
Q2: load existing feed, check ATOM feed is new
Q1: $set feeds => [RSS]
Q2: $set feeds => [ATOM]
```

Now RSS feed is lost.

If we pick `$push` or `$addToSet`, then following may happen.

```
User A added a site, putting RSS feed to Q1
User B added the same site, putting the same RSS feed to Q2
Q1: load existing feed, check RSS feed is new
Q2: load existing feed, check RSS feed is new
Q1: $push RSS
Q2: $push RSS
```

Now RSS feed has been duplicated

If our data model were simply `{ url }`, then `$addToSet` will safeguard against duplicate feed. But unfortunately this is not the case, the `date` attribute may differ. So `$addToSet` is not much safer than `$push`.

We have thought of a few possible workaround to this problem, but none are great given our tight schedule.

1. Decouple feeds from site into its own collection, safeguard with `url` alone, and change our model and repository accordingly.
2. Insert a partial `{ url }` into the site model first, then update them with addition information, this should makes `$addToSet` usable, but may break other queue that require `date` to always be present (testing needed).
3. Let race condition happen as-is, `$push` the feed first, use a background queue to detect duplicate and remove them later.

(There might be a 4th solution if upsert work with positional query, but as far as I know MongoDB v2.4 doesn't have it yet)

**So I wonder whether there are better alternative for resolving this kind of race condition. Or if there are some best practices for it.**

Comment: You are most likely using the store wrong. With document based databases you have to store the information of uniqueness as part of the composed name of the value so that duplication does not occur. So you keep one subdocument for RSS and one for ATOM in your example. You  have to think out of the box and turn that what you think is a race-condition in just standard work with inconsistent and eventually duplicated data.

Comment: @hakre thx, if so then we need to generate some sort of slug for each feed url because there can be multiple RSS/ATOM feed. this unfortunately does require quite a bit of change to model, but i agree that this approach makes sense.

Comment: @hakre actually I would like double-confirm if you are suggesting turning `feeds` from array to object (or split into separate attributes). This approach requires relaxing our validation, which guard by column name like traditional RDBMS validation (plus we might have more than 1 ATOM and 1 RSS feed to deal with). Otherwise i don't see how we could keep ourselves from write skew using array.

Comment: If you guard something like traditionally RDBMS, you are using the wrong tool for the job, Mongo ain't RDBMS (nor a parcticularly well document based database). Consider the right tool for the job, otherwise you'll end up with a constant stream of questions that *"are not particularly answered to the level of detail you need"*.

Comment: @hakre given we are actually storing the feed items as document, in a separate collection, i do think this tool fits our need quite well. in this case a site can only have a few feeds, and if we read the mongodb doc right, embed is the right option for such meta data. The only problem is we would like to avoid duplication of meta data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a gard on the update selector:

```
alice(mongod-2.4.8) test> db.foo.save({_id: 12 })
Updated 1 new record(s) in 1ms
alice(mongod-2.4.8) test> db.foo.update({ _id: 12, "feeds.url" : {$ne: "baz"} }, 
    { $push :     { feeds : { url: "baz" } } } )
Updated 1 existing record(s) in 1ms
alice(mongod-2.4.8) test> db.foo.update({ _id: 12, "feeds.url" : {$ne: "baz"} },
    { $push : { feeds : { url: "baz" } } } )
Updated 0 record(s) in 1ms
alice(mongod-2.4.8) test> db.foo.find({_id: 12 })
{
    "_id": 12,
    "feeds": [
        {
            "url": "baz"
        }
    ]
}
Fetched 1 record(s) in 1ms -- Index[_id_]
```

Comment: upon see this i was like: how didn't we think of it? this is certainly a valid solution.

Comment: This is easily the best answer, will work in mongodbs environment, a distributed sharded set of data

Answer (score 4):

you might want to have a look at [tokumx](http://www.tokutek.com/products/tokumx-for-mongodb/), a fork of mongodb which supports [transactions](http://www.tokutek.com/2013/10/introducing-tokumx-transactions-for-mongodb-applications/) (besides a few other usefull things)

Comment: Since the whole purpose of MongoDB is to be used in a sharded distributed setup I would think that using toku transactions kind of defeats the point of using MongoDB